# Search engines and XML Sitemap

Tags: sitecore, sitemap, sitecore8

Do the search engines find the XML sitemap file even without the existence of the robots.txt file?

If the robots.txt doesn't exist; Is http://yourweb/sitemap.xml the default URL that will be used by search engines?

What is the best technique that can be used to implement a handler for /sitemap.xml URL to server multiple sitemap in sitecore multi site environment?

The following are some options for the last question:

- https://laubplusco.net/creating-a-customhandler-in-sitecore/
- http://sitecorefromarg.blogspot.com/2014/12/simple-sitemap-xml.html
- https://superruub.wordpress.com/2012/09/24/sitemap-xml-for-multiple-sites-under-sitecore/

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because "more than 1 question". Actually there are 3 separate questions; 3rd asking for an opinion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I suggest you to use a module:

https://marketplace.sitecore.net/Modules/U/Ultimate_Sitemap_XML.aspx

or 
https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/XML_Sitemap_Generator.aspx

or 
https://marketplace.sitecore.net/en/Modules/Sitemap_XML.aspx

I preferred first one, it's compatible with Sitecore 8.

The module includes the following new features:

- Shared content support
- Custom MVC rendering for displaying a sitemap on a page
- Content controlled sitemap settings
- Page sitemap base template (inherited by page templates and adds
  sitemap-related meta fields)

Original Sitemap XML features retained:

- Multisite support
- robots.txt file generation and updates
- Physical XML sitemap file generation
- /sitemap.xml dynamic handler
- Auto sitemap submission to search engines on publish

The module documentation can also be located in the package Read Me section, 
which can be viewed during the installation, or on the Sitecore Best Practices website Modules Page.

For Robots.txt you can use this module

https://sitecoreclimber.wordpress.com/2014/07/27/sitecore-multisite-robots-txt/ 
or

http://sitecorecorner.com/2014/07/30/handling-sitecore-multi-site-instance-robots-txt/

These module are creating a handler, and you have robots.txt without creating a physical file.